# Use sed to format huge files

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a test file that is 4.5GB and I am trying to format it.

First I am trying to replace the tabs with ',' and also separate each column field with a `"`.

Second I am formatting a date field in the file with awk and sed.

Here is what I am using:

For formatting:

```
cat test_sample.csv | sed -e 's/"/""/g' | sed -e 's/\t/","/g' | sed -e 's/$/"/g' | sed -e 's/^/"/' > test_sample.csv
```

For Date:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} NR>1{cmd = "date -d \"" $10 "\" \"+%Y-%m-%d\"";cmd | getline out; $10=out; close("uuidgen")} 1' test_sample.csv > _report.tmp && mv _report.tmp test_sample.csv
```

These commands are runnig fine for small files but are failing and is clearing all the data in the file.

Please can someone help me format this file?

Comment: Do you have (or can you install) GNU awk for time functions?

Comment: You probably don't need to call date and getline and so your script could be orders of magnitude more efficient. If you edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output we could help you. Actually at this point you may want to make it a separate followup question since you already accepted an answer to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They also clear small files because redirection happens first, so the file gets truncated and stays empty.

Consider:

```
$ cat file.txt
A line of text
$ cat file.txt > file.txt
$ cat file.txt      # Empty!
```

To avoid that, you have to copy to a temporary file – which the `-i` option in sed does for you. It optionally takes an extension:

```
sed -i.bak '...'
```

This addresses your file truncation problem.

As for the rest:

- Don't call sed many times like this:

  ```
  sed 's/pattern1/replacement1/' file | sed 's/pattern2/replacement2/' | ...
  ```

  This goes for each command through the complete file, making the process much slower. Use this instead:

  ```
  sed 's/pattern1/replacement1/;s/pattern2/replacement2/...'
  ```

  to process the file just once.
- You don't have to use `cat` to pipe into sed: sed takes a filename as an argument and you can avoid this [Useless Use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Even more so if you combine the commands and avoid all pipes, see below.
- Don't combine sed and awk. As a rule of thumb, if you use awk anywhere, you don't need sed.

A combined single-pass in-place sed command could look like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
sed -i 's/"/""/g;s/\t/","/g;s/$/"/;s/^/"/' test_sample.csv
```

And reducing everything to a single awk command (not as one-liner friendly any longer, but definitely faster than combining sed and awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR > 1 {
    gsub(/"/, "\"\"")
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        $i = "\"" $i "\""
    cmd = "date -d \"" $10 "\" \"+%Y-%m-%d\""
    cmd | getline out
    $10 = out
    close("uuidgen")
    print
}' test_sample.csv > _report.tmp && mv _report.tmp test_sample.csv
```

---

<sup>1</sup> BSD sed as found in Mac OS requires `-i''`.

Comment: While I agree with all of your answer, I don't think piping output of sed to another imposes too much of an overhead compared to chaining them using `;`. Since in both context, sed puts the line back in to pattern space to modify it.

Comment: @jaypalsingh It makes a difference if there are replacements on each line (not a big difference between piping and using `;`) or just very few in the whole file (lots of overhead due to processing the complete file multiple times), so I'd say there are scenarios where they're similar, some where piping is slower, but none where piping is faster - why not make it a habit to always use the potentially faster one.

Comment: Right, I'm wasn't suggesting piping would be faster, just wasn't too sure if that could _slow_ things down significantly. I personally prefer not to pipe as well so I can't complain. `:)` All great suggestions BTW that should resolve OP's issues.

Comment: @jaypalsingh Thanks! I haven't actually benchmarked the difference ever, but it would be interesting to see.

Comment: @EdMorton Eh, I assumed some magic happening elsewhere that requires it, as it was in OP's original awk command ;)

Comment: Oh, I thought you had just meant to write `close(cmd)` since that's missing at that point in the script. You really should be protecting against getline failure too btw - as written a getline failure would pass silently unnoticed and duplicate the last successful `date` output. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline for how to call getline safely if/when necessary.

Comment: Actually, reading the script now - I bet none of that is necessary anyway as it looks like the OP is using `date` to change one date format to another so (s)he probably just needs to split/recombine the date string and shouldn't be calling `date` and `getline` at all. Without sample input/output though, who knows....?

Comment: @EdMorton Exactly, input/output is missing, but the main point of the question was the truncation due to redirection, and the main point of the answer is to point out that the tools shouldn't be mixed in the first place. The actual script is more of a proof of concept. Thanks for the getline link, btw!